# How to use JDO persistence manager?

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, persistence-manager

I have two questions regarding how to create / use the JDO persistence manager (PM, hereafter).

Say, in a Java web application, if I have 10 entities, which can be logically grouped into 2 groups (for example, 5 user related entities and 5 business related entities)

1. Should I need two different PMs to manage these 2 groups or only one PM is enough?
2. Regarding the initialization, shall I use singleton instance of a PM (which will be shared by all the user's using the app at a given point of time) or should I create a PM for each and every session?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [JDO Documentation](http://db.apache.org/jdo/pmf.html) you create one `PersistenceManagerFactory` per datastore. If you are using JDO to access databases via SQL and you have more than one database, then you will need one `PersistenceManagerFactory` per database (since you need to specify the JDBC URL, user name and password when you create the `PersistenceManagerFactory`).

For simple use cases, you can just create a `PersistenceManager` when you need it and close it in a `finally` clause (see [the persistence manager documentation](http://db.apache.org/jdo/pm.html)).

If you use transactions, and the code for updating entities can be spread across multiple methods or objects, I recommend creating the `PersistenceManager` on demand and storing it in a `ThreadLocal` (or request-scoped object if you use Guice or Spring). This will make sure any code that does updates participates in the current transaction. Make sure to close the `PersistenceManager` at the end of the request.

If you only need one persistence manager factory, you can do:

```
public class Datastore {
  private static PersistenceManagerFactory PMF;
  private static final ThreadLocal<PersistenceManager> PER_THREAD_PM
      = new ThreadLocal<PersistenceManager>();

  public static void initialize() {
     if (PMF != null) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("initialize() already called");
     }
     PMF = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("jdo.properties");
  }

  public static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PER_THREAD_PM.get();
    if (pm == null) {
      pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
      PER_THREAD_PM.set(pm);
    }
    return pm;
  }

  public static void finishRequest() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PER_THREAD_PM.get();
    if (pm != null) {
      PER_THREAD_PM.remove();
      Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
      if (tx.isActive()) {
         tx.rollback();
      }
      pm.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Any code that needs a persistence manager can call `Datastore.getPersistenceManager()`

Note: I used all static methods to make it simple for the purposes of answering your question. If I was using a dependency-injection framework like Guice, I would make the methods non-static and bind `Datastore` as a Singleton.

You could call `finishRequest` in a Servlet Filter:

```
public class PersistenceManagerFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

  public init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    Datastore.initialize();
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
      Datastore.finishRequest();
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue: do a search/replace and change all occurrences of 'persistAnce' to 'persistEnce' and you'll be much happier. :-)

Comment: I found this approach doesn't work on google app engine - for whatever reason it works perfectly on localhost but the pmf is closed at unexpected times in production

Comment: @bsautner If you post a question with your problem and provide a link here, I'd be happy to look at it. I haven't used GAE in a while though.